# budget calculator app in js (function not working)

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to do this js budget calculator app. I have gotten as far as you can see below with the help of chat gpt. I got stuck on the delete function. The `transactionDelete` should remove the transaction either from the income area and expense area. It should also update the `newMoneyArr` and display it in the available balance.

```js
const incomeSection = document.querySelector(".income-area");
const expensesSection = document.querySelector(".expenses-area");
const availableMoney = document.querySelector(".available-money");
const addTransactionPanel = document.querySelector(".add-transaction-panel");

const nameInput = document.querySelector("#name");
const amountInput = document.querySelector("#amount");
const categorySelect = document.querySelector("#category");
const errorTransactionname = document.querySelector(".error-transaction-name");
const errorTransactionAmount = document.querySelector(
  ".error-transaction-amount"
);
const errorTransactionOption = document.querySelector(
  ".error-transaction-option"
);
const errorMsg = document.querySelector(".error-msg");

const addTransactionBtn = document.querySelector(".add-transaction");
const saveBtn = document.querySelector(".save");
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".cancel");
const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector(".delete-all");


let ID = 0;
let newMoneyArr
let moneyArr = []


const checkTransactionName = () => {
  if (nameInput.value.length == 0) {
    errorTransactionname.style.display = "block";
    errorTransactionname.innerHTML = "Transaction name cannot be empty!";
  } else if (nameInput.value.length > 10) {
    errorTransactionname.style.display = "block";
    errorTransactionname.innerHTML =
      "Transaction name cannot be longer then 10 charcters";
  } else {
    errorTransactionname.innerHTML = "";
  }
};

const checkTransactionAmount = () => {
  if (amountInput.value.length == 0) {
    errorTransactionAmount.style.display = "block";
    errorTransactionAmount.innerHTML = "Transaction amount cannot be empty!";
  } else if (amountInput.value.length >= 6) {
    errorTransactionAmount.style.display = "block";
    errorTransactionAmount.innerHTML =
      "Transaction amount cannot be longer then 5 digits";
  } else {
    errorTransactionAmount.innerHTML = "";
  }
};

const checkSelect = () => {
  if (categorySelect.selectedIndex == 0) {
    errorTransactionOption.style.display = "block";
    errorTransactionOption.innerHTML = "Choose one of the two options";
  } else {
    errorTransactionOption.innerHTML = "";
  }
};

const createTransaction = () => {
  checkTransactionName();
  checkTransactionAmount();
  checkSelect();

  if (
    errorTransactionAmount.innerHTML != "" ||
    errorTransactionAmount.innerHTML != "" ||
    errorTransactionOption.innerHTML != ""
  ) {
    errorMsg.style.display = "block";
    errorMsg.innerHTML = "Fill out all the spaces correctly please";
  } else {
    let newTransaction = document.createElement("li");
    newTransaction.setAttribute("id", ID);
    newTransaction.classList.add("transaction");
    newTransaction.innerHTML = `<p class="transaction-name">${nameInput.value}</p>
                                    <p class="transaction-amount">${amountInput.value}zł
                                    <button onclick = 'transactionDelete(${ID})' class="delete">
                                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></p>`;

    let newTransactionValue = newTransaction.childNodes[2].textContent;


    if (categorySelect.selectedIndex == 1) {
      incomeSection.appendChild(newTransaction);
      newTransaction.classList.add("income-transaction");
    } else {
      expensesSection.appendChild(newTransaction);
      newTransaction.classList.add("expense-transaction");
      let newAmount2 = parseFloat(amountInput.value);
      let newAmount = -newAmount2;

    }

    ID++;

    newBalance();
    closePanel();
  }
};

const newBalance = () => {
  if (categorySelect.selectedIndex == 1) {
    moneyArr.push(parseFloat(amountInput.value));
  } else {
    let newAmount2 = parseFloat(amountInput.value);
    let newAmount = -newAmount2;
    console.log(newAmount);
    moneyArr.push(newAmount);
  }

  let newMoneyArr = moneyArr.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  });

};


const clearInputs = () => {
  nameInput.value = "";
  amountInput.value = "";
  categorySelect.selectedIndex = 0;
  errorTransactionname.innerHTML = "";
  errorTransactionAmount.innerHTML = "";
  errorTransactionOption.innerHTML = "";
  errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
};

saveBtn.addEventListener("click", createTransaction);

addTransactionBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (showPanel = () => {
    addTransactionPanel.style.display = "flex";
  })
);

cancelBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (closePanel = () => {
    addTransactionPanel.style.display = "none";
    clearInputs();
  })
);

const deleteAllTransactions = () => {
  incomeSection.innerHTML = "<h3>Income</h3>";
  expensesSection.innerHTML = "<h3>Expenses</h3>";
  availableMoney.textContent = "0$";
  moneyArr = [0];
};

deleteAllBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteAllTransactions);

//stuck on this function
transactionDelete = (id) => {
  const transactionToDelete = document.getElementById(id);
  const transactionAmount = parseFloat(transactionToDelete.childNodes[2].innerText);

  if (transactionToDelete.classList.contains('income-transaction')) {
    incomeSection.removeChild(transactionToDelete);

  } else {
    expensesSection.removeChild(transactionToDelete);
  }

};
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,400,700&display=swap&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6c5198f753.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <h1><i class="fas fa-wallet"></i> Wallet</h1>
  <p>Finace manager</p>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="transactions-wrapper">
    <section class="transactions">
      <h2 class="title">Transaction list</h2>
      <div class="transaction-list">
        <div class="income-area">
          <h3>Income</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="expenses-area">
          <h3>Expenses</h3>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <section class="options">
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">Available money:</h2>
      <p class="available-money">0$</p>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button class="add-transaction"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> add transaction</button>
      <button class="delete-all"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> delete everything</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
</div>
<div class="add-transaction-panel">
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <h2 class="title">add new transaction</h2>

    <div class="form-box">
      <label for="name">name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name"></input>
      <p class="error-transaction-name"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-box">
      <label for="amount">amount:</label>
      <input type="number" id="amount">
      <p class="error-transaction-amount"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-box">
      <label for="category">select category:</label>
      <select id="category">
        <option value="none" selected>chose if the transaction is a income or expense</option>
        <option value="income">income</option>
        <option value="shopping">expense</option>
      </select>
      <p class="error-transaction-option"></p>

    </div>
    <p class="error-msg"></p>
    <div class="panel-buttons">
      <button class="save" type="button"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> save</button>
      <button class="cancel" type="button"><i class="far fa-window-close"></i> cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You will need to share a [mcve] of the code you're using.

Comment: `The transactionDelete should remove the transaction either from the income area and expense area. It should also update the newMoneyArr and display it in the available balance.` Does the function execute either of these actions? If not, does it do anything? Is there an error?